# Changing shared variables from multiple threads c++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I was wondering if there was any way to achieve changing shared/global variables from multiple threads in c++

Imagine this code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <thread>

void pushanother(int x);

std::vector<int> myarr;

void main() {
    myarr.push_back(0);

    std::thread t1(pushanother, 2);

    t1.join();
}

void pushanother(int x) {
    myarr.push_back(x);
}
```

Comment: You should protect access to `myarr` using a mutex. Also `join()` the thread before `main()` exits. Last but probably not least, you're missing a forward declaration for `pushanother()`.

Comment: Simply example code:
Just trying to talk about the error created here, as it breaks on the pushanother function.

Comment: Post a [MCVE] along with the verbatim error text please. [edit] your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this particular case, the code is (barring the lack of a join on the thread), surprisingly ok.

This is because the constructor of `std::thread` causes a memory fence operation and the first thread does not modify or read the state of the vector after this fence.

In effect you have transferred control of the vector to the second thread.

However, modifying the code to represent a more normal situation requires explicit locks:

```
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

void pushanother(int x);

// mutex to handle contention of shared resource
std::mutex m;

// the shared resource
std::vector<int> myarr;

auto push_it(int i) -> void
{
    // take a lock...
    auto lock = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(m);

    // modify/read the resource
    myarr.push_back(i);

    // ~lock implicitly releases the lock
}

int main() {

    std::thread t1(pushanother, 2);

    push_it(0);

    t1.join();
}

void pushanother(int x) {
    push_it(x);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The code seems to work, I was just playing with mutex's but thanks for the example.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the exact complete example for your problem:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/mutex/mutex/